# Editing "Project" file in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I am working with a Joomla template and attempting to change the overall font used throughout. I am using Chrome/Inspect element to search the code. I found where to make the change in Inspect Element but I cannot find where this file is anywhere in the directory.

The code appears in the "matched CSS rules" section of chrome's inspect element. The path is listed as "domainname/templatename/:393

I assume this means line 393 but it does not tell me which file. Usually this would tell me which css or php file to edit.

If I click on the link to show me the full file (this can be done in Inspect Element) it just says "(program)" instead of something obvious like template.css or index.php.

Does anyone know which file this would be? I have checked index.php and many of the .css files but I cannot find where to make the change.

Here are 2 snapshots to show what I mean.

http://bit.ly/153W40n and http://bit.ly/1f7IJJW

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is an embeded style. Try to search on the template directory, specially on /templates/your_template/index.php and in any php or css under /templates/your_template/html

If it is not there then you must locate the extensions which generates this code and patch it via template override.

Good luck.

Comment: This is correct.  Since you don't know if it's coming from the template or an extensions' view or a view override, simply search for substrings of the style rules.  They will be inserted most likely with the JDocument function addStyleDeclaration, use that as a search in combination with _component_wrap (the rest seems dynamic)